What could be causing: MongoServerError: Regular expression is invalid: UTF-8 error: byte 2 top bits not 0x80
I get this MongoDB error when trying to query from the DB using regex, which is supposed to ignore diacritics in the fields. I believe the RegExp query is the part causing the error. Is there anything wrong with the RegExp or what could cause this error?
Thanks in advance for any possible solutions.
PS: I am accessing the mongoose directly over PayloadCMS's local API.
PPS: The error rate is not 100%, sometimes it is working, sometimes it is not. I was not able the find out, when and why the query fails.
const cleanedQuery = removeDiacritics(query)
result = await payload.db.collections[collection].find(
  {
    [queryField]: {
      $regex: RegExp(cleanedQuery, 'i'),
    },
  },
  {
    _id: 1,
    [queryField]: 1,
  },
  {
    limit: 3,
  },
)

Diacritics RexExp function:
function removeDiacritics(string = '') {
  return string
    .replace(/a/g, '[a,á,à,ä,â]')
    .replace(/A/g, '[A,a,á,à,ä,â]')
    .replace(/e/g, '[e,é,ë,è]')
    .replace(/E/g, '[E,e,é,ë,è]')
    .replace(/i/g, '[i,í,ï,ì]')
    .replace(/I/g, '[I,i,í,ï,ì]')
    .replace(/o/g, '[o,ó,ö,ò]')
    .replace(/O/g, '[O,o,ó,ö,ò]')
    .replace(/u/g, '[u,ü,ú,ù]')
    .replace(/U/g, '[U,u,ü,ú,ù]')
}


To help us understand your intended usage, please provide an example value for query and furthermore, provide the expected result for $regex

Potentially unrelated, but there was a critical advisory issued this week at https://www.mongodb.com/resources/products/alerts/potential-data-integrity-issues-sep-2024. If you were using the Node.js driver and Node v22.7.0 to write data it's possible invalid UTF-8 strings may have been written.

Thanks! The issue was really related to Node v22, after switching back to Node v20, the bug was no longer appearing.
